# How to connect php to google SMTP and send mail?

Tags: php, email, smtp

I need a help in this issue, i can't connect to smtp and can't send. i tried different solutions from other question but nothing, can someone give me a good explanation step-by-step what to do..i'm new to php. I've done email-sending, sms-sending with python but i can't get good documentation with php. please help. thanks

Comment: please put some code so that we can check where is the problem.

Comment: http://www.9lessons.info/2009/10/send-mail-using-smtp-and-php.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend using PHPMailer, heres a example http://phpmailer.worxware.com/?pg=examplebgmail for smtp

`$mail->Host = "smtp.gmail.com";  //If you have a business gmail account
Username   = "yourusername@gmail.com"; //Your login email username
Password   = "yourpassword"; //Your password`

For password use a 2-way verification using Admin panel. it would look something like wqhggkdhufjsjkpftj

Comment: i've already tried but no success..

Comment: Please put up code for us to see